# Is there a hot-key that qualifies email recipients while entering recipients names within a corporate directory?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've recently had a career move.  The company that I work for uses Outlook 2010, and my former company (which I worked for for over 8 years) used Lotus Notes.

What I can't find within Outlook is a way to auto-complete, or search for contacts, as I enter their names into the "To:" field, if the recipient isn't in my local contacts group, but is within our massive corporate directory.

While typing, is there a key that I can press that will attempt to auto-validate my entry when I enter a users name and, hopefully, make suggestions if there are any naming conflicts?

Comment: You can turn on and off automatic name check... http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-off-automatic-name-checking-and-completion-HP005243171.aspx I don't see a keyboard sequence to call check names tho without using the button on the ribbon

Comment: @Tyson, those instructions are for outlook 2003.  I'm using 2010 and since MS went to that blasted toolstrip, I can't find a "tools" menu, nor this option from the Options dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will check names for validity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking the <kbd>To:</kbd> button? This will bring up a search box where you can search the company directory. It will search as you type finding the closest matches.

Once you've sent an email to someone once, you should just be able to use the normal address box to search for their name and auto-complete it by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Since he's asking the question, I don't think his auto check and auto complete are turned on.

Comment: I certainly can click on the "To:" field/button and, in fact, I have.  I just know that multiple other email tools have had a quicker way of searching corporate contact dbs, which is where the contact dialog defaults to when I click on the To field.  The auto-complete does work, but only for contacts that I've added to my personal contact list.  I'd prefer, however, for auto-complete to do a look up from my corporate contacts list (which probably has over 10k contacts.)